# HTML: Including spaces in default input values

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, ejs

I am trying to add some CRUD functionality to my web app and I am having a little trouble conquering this tiny details.

I am pulling in some data from express into my EJS template. I have some form fields in a table I will make visible upon clicking the 'edit' button.

I want the data from corresponding row to auto-populate the form fields.

As of now, only the first word is being populated into the field, but the remaining words are being excluded.

Here is the EJS.

```
<% if (expenses.length > 0) { %>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Category</th>
            <th>Date</th>
            <th>Place</th>
            <th>Description</th>
            <th>Price</th>
            <th>Edit</th>
        </tr>
        <% expenses.forEach(expense => { %>
            <tr>
                <td><%=expense.category%></td>
                <td><%=expense.date%></td>
                <td><%=expense.place%></td>
                <td><%=expense.description%></td>
                <td><%=expense.price%></td>
                <td>
                    <button>Edit</button>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <form action=<%="/expense/updateExpense/" + invoice._id%>>
                    <td>
                        <select name="expense_category" id="expense_category">
                            <option value=<%=expense.category%>></option>
                            <% categories.forEach(category => { %>
                                <option value=<%=category.name%>><%=category.name%></option>
                            <% }) %>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" name="expense_date" value=<%=expense.date%>>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" name="expense_place" value=<%=expense.place%>>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" name="expense_description" value=<%=expense.description%>>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" name="expense_price" value=<%=expense.price%>>
                    </td>
                </form>
            </tr>
        <% }) %>
    </table>
<% } %>
```

Now lets zoom in on a specific row I am talking about

```
<td>
   <input type="text" name="expense_place" value=<%=expense.place%>>
</td>
```

The value of 'expense.place' should read, "Sam's Club" but only the word "Sam's" is being populated into the input field.

I have tried doing `expense.place.split(' ')` but this returns `"Sam's,Club"` and then I tried doing `expense.place.split(' ').join(' ')` and it just returns `Sam's`.

Does anybody have any advice for me on this one?

Comment: Not exactly. In this case, if I add quotes to the value it just reads everything in the string directly. For example, if I say value=<%='expense.place'%> then the value is set to 'expense.place' and not the actual value of expense.place

Comment: NEVERMIND this actually worked! I just had to set it as value="<%=expense.place%>" thank you so much!